# Sections inside slides for vertical scrolling using fullPage.js

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

I'm trying to reproduce the following structure using fullPage.js:

[image]

The problem I have is how I include (if it is possible) in the second slide three sections so as to achieve vertical scrolling.

Another possible solution could be two create 4 slides (red ones) for the first section and then somehow modify them in order to have vertical scrolling:

[image]

I only want this behavior for the second slide of the first section.

Comment: fullPage.js doesn't work that way. It doesn't provide any way to deal with your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply